# Should we have a designated page for site rules?

Tags: feature-request

This has happened to me a couple of times now. I visit a new Stack Exchange community where I don't normally frequent. I feel like maybe my question belongs there, but I fear it might also fall into the off-topic category based on that community's rules.

Where do I go to view the rules though? Maybe they are buried somewhere in the Meta, where I will find a post that explains some of them, but is that all of them? It seems like this is a grey area.

I know the sites are very different in nature, but I'm imagining something like reddit's “Rules” column. It's specific to each subreddit, and you always know where to look for it. I'm not saying SE should be more like reddit, just offering an example I hope will be easily understood.

So, what do you all think? Would you welcome such a feature? Or does it exist somewhere and I just don't know where? Come to think of it, I'm not even sure if *this* question is on-topic. But I don't know where to look to check....

Comment: Every site has their help pages ([sitename].stackexchange.com/help). Are you talking about something separate from that?

Comment: @Catija That's exactly the page I'm talking about! I was searching with keywords like "rules" and "guidelines" which is probably why I didn't find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every site has a Help Center, reached through the "?" icon in the top bar.  Every help center has a page called "What topics can I ask about here?", which describes that site's scope.  On many sites, this page links to other pages, either in the help center or on meta, where points are further clarified.  Examples: [1](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) [2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) [3](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

If the help center on a particular site is more minimalist, you can check for a "faq" tag on the per-site meta and/or post on the site's meta asking that the help-center page be improved.  Moderators can edit "what to ask" and the tour.  (The tour provides a quick overview and is usually less detailed than "what to ask".)